# How can I use a join for two columns corresponding to the same primary key?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with five columns:

```
streetId, streetName, areaId, ISfSectionId1, ISFsectionId2
```

where `areaId` is a foreign key for table `area` and `isfsectionid1` and `isfsectionid2` are foreign keys for the same primary key `isfsectionId` (isfsectionId2 can have null value).

I am using this query to join them

```
SELECT 
    s.streetId, s.streetName, a.areaName, i.isfsectionName, d.ISFsectionName
FROM
    area a 
INNER JOIN
    street s ON s.areaId = a.areaId 
INNER JOIN
    ISFsections i ON s.fasileone = i.ISFsectionId 
JOIN
    ISFsections d ON s.fasiletwo = d.ISFsectionId
```

Without that last join, it is working fine, but when adding the last join, it's returning records for the ISFsectionId2 only.

What is the problem?

Comment: Try `LEFT JOIN`s instead

Comment: When isfsectionId2 is null you will get no rows if you use inner join with it. Go for a left join there like M. Ali says

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT s.streetId
      ,s.streetName
      ,a.areaName
      ,i.isfsectionName
      ,d.ISFsectionName
from       area        a 
INNER join street      s on s.areaId = a.areaId 
LEFT join  ISFsections i on s.fasileone = i.ISFsectionId 
LEFT join  ISFsections d on s.fasiletwo = d.ISFsectionId
```